# Exclude destination files/directories form robocopy?

Tags: robocopy

I have a deploy process that is currently using this robocopy command:

`robocopy [source] [destination] /MIR /XF [file pattern] /XD [directory pattern]`

The `[destination]` may have additional files or directories added to it outside this process that the `[source]` does not. The `/MIR` flag is present because if I add files or directories to `[source]` I want them to appear in the `[destination]`. Also, if I remove a file/directory from `[source]` that exists in `[destination]` I want to remove that from `[destination]`.  However, this will also remove any of the new files/directories that may have been added to `[destination]`.

The `/XF` and `/XD` flags appear to only restrict the source files/directories. Is there a corresponding way to exclude destination files from the copy? Something to indicate "When doing `\MIR` don't delete directories starting with the string 'new'," for example.

Answer (score 2):

Should have run more tests before asking. It appears that amending the command to be:

`robocopy [source] [destination] /MIR /XF [file pattern] /XD [source directory pattern] "new*"`

Does, in fact, ignore directories in the `[destination]` that have "new" as the start of their name.